# Retrieving User Profile Emails from Sharepoint Shared Services Provider (SSP) for newsletter

Tags: sharepoint-2007, profile, ssp

I was wondering if there is an easy way for me to retrieve all the users profile for the **entire sharepoint farm** for me to do a periodic newsletter.

I tried googling quite a bit and it seems that we can retrieve all the sharepoint users of a particular group by the below **webservice**:

http://share2003/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?WSDL

However, that will be users limited to that particular **sharepoint site collection**.  There might be other users who belong to the Sharepoint Farm, i.e. with a MySite account but not belonging to that particular sharepoint site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use http:///_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx

```
GetUserProfileByIndex
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981288%28office.12%29.aspx

http://markiwaszko.blogspot.com/2007/08/moss-getuserprofilebyindexint-index.html

Maybe use the count as well

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981209%28office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like exactly what I need... especially for the 2nd link, i.e.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like exactly what I need... especially for the 2nd link, i.e.